# Import Error. Circular References

Tags: python, hierarchy, importerror

I have a package like this

```
package/
    __init__.py
    subpackage1/
        __init__.py
        moduleA.py
        moduleB.py
        moduleC.py
        moduleD.py
    subpackage2/
       __init__.py
       moduleX.py
       moduleY.py
       moduleZ.py
```

In moduleB.py, I am importing

```
from moduleA import bar
```

In moduleA, I am importing

```
from moduleB import foo
```

I am getting ImportError.

```
ImportError: cannot import name foo
```

What could be the problem here ? and to avoid this problem, what should I do ? and what should I write in **_*init*_**.py pf package, subpackage1, subpackage2 ?

_***init*_**.py of subpackage1

```
from moduleA import *
from moduleB import *
from moudleC import *
from moudleD import *
```

_***init*_**.py of subpackage2

```
from moduleX import *
from moduleY import *
from moduleZ import *
```

_***init*_**.py of package

```
from subpackage1 import *
from subpackage2 import *
```

Is there some problem with my **_*init*_**.py files ?

**EDIT**:
I have changed imports

moduleB

```
from .moduleA import bar
```

moduleA

```
from .moduleB import foo
```

Still, I am getting the same import error.

```
ImportError: cannot import name foo
```

**EDIT**:

moduleB

```
def Bar():
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = Foo()
        self.val = 10
        .
        .
```

moduleA

```
def Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = Bar()
        self.val = 5
        .
        .
```

I want to do this. And I insist on keeping both classes in different files. How should I import ?

Comment: I think you mean class Foo and class Bar?  Either way, I show a few examples of how to do it in my answer.  only one of either ModuleB or ModuleA has to follow one of the patterns I show, the other can still do it at the top.  Any other questions?

Comment: thanks. it's working. but I'm getting RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded. I'm calling Foo from Bar and Bar from Foo. I'll look into it.

Comment: You're welcome. Sounds like you have some infinite recursion going on there, which is to be expected if you're creating a new one of the other each time you initialize each of them.  You'll need to re-think your design.  Maybe you can just pass in a reference from Foo() when you instantiate Bar(). That way, bar has a foo.  E.g. in Bar: (__init__(self, foo):  self.foo = foo )  and in Foo: (__init__(self): self.bar = Bar(self) )

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It actually appears to be a problem with circular imports.

Your moduleB says "from moduleA import bar", which tries to load moduleA, but the first thing it encounters in moduleA is "from moduleB import foo", which sends it back to moduleB.  So you have an unresolvable bit of circular recursion there.

Typically (but not always) a circular import is an indicator that you need to rethink or re-architect how you're doing things. There are, however, a few possible work-arounds out there.

One is to move the import statement to the bottom of your python file (assuming you're using foo or bar inside of another function, so its not getting called instantly when the file loads)

e.g.

```
#ModuleB.py 
class Bar(object):   
  def __init__(self):
    self.foo = Foo()
    self.val = 10
    .
    .
# at bottom of file
from moduleA import Foo
```

another alternative is to place the import statement inside a function, called the "lazy import" pattern:

```
#ModuleB.py 
class Bar(object):   
  def __init__(self):
    from moduleA import Foo
    self.foo = Foo()
    self.val = 10
```

As to your question about the `__init__.py` files. I see no reason why you wouldn't leave them empty.  The empty `__init__.py` files simply tell python "this directory is a python package" and permit imports.

Typically you would have a file in your package directory that "runs" your program by importing and utilizing modules from the subpackages.  So assuming such file (e.g., package/main.py) exists, your imports would look like the following, with just empty `__init__.py` files.

```
#package/main.py
from subpackage1.moduleA import bar  # you can now call bar() directly
from subpackage1 import moduleB  # you can now call foo like: moduleB.foo()
from subpackage2.moduleX import jah
```

What you're doing above essentially takes all of the functions and attributes of all of the Modules in each subpackage and makes them available directly on the subpackage as if they were the subpackage's functions and attributes (so you could `import subpackage1` and call `subpackage1.bar()` and `subpackage.foo()`  instead of `subpackage.moduleA.bar()`, etc.), but I don't get the impression thats what you were trying to do, necessarily, and there's probably no reason to do it in this case.

If you need to use something in subpackage2 in a module in subpackage1, see the answers to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python)  Or google how to add directories to your python path.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't to do with hierarchy, it's to do with circular references. You can't tell file A to import file B, and file B to import file A - since they depend on each other, the circle can't be resolved.

Either restructure your files so that they don't need to import each other - remember Python is not Java, you can have more than one class in a file - or move one of the imports into a function so that it doesn't have to execute at import time.