# How to solve infinite loop import?

Tags: python, class, import, module

I want to understand the root of my problem. I have encountered this a couple times and it is quite time consuming to figure it out each time.

This time I feel like I have missed something that I thought I understood.
A related question is posted here: [Infinite loop with Python imports; looking for Pythonic way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12474374/infinite-loop-with-python-imports-looking-for-pythonic-way)

I decided my modules present an infinite loop, but I still get the same error. so here are what I have.
I have included `__init__.py` files here too because I suspect that this file might cause behavior that I am currently unaware of.

In `sources/preparation/features/__Init__.py`:

```
from .build_features import *
from .get_qualified_edges import *
from .select_strategy import *
from .test import *
```

In `sources/preprocessing/__init__.py`, I have:

```
from .apply_preprocessing import *
from .convertion import *
```

In `sources/preprocessing/apply_preprocessing` I have:

```
from Sources.Preparation.Features.get_qualified_edges import get_all_GeneDisease_unweighted_disease2disease_qualified_edges
from Sources.Preparation.Features.get_qualified_edges import get_GPSim_disease2disease_qualified_edgesjk
```

In directory `source/preparation/features/get_qualified_edges.py`:

```
from Sources.Preprocessing.convertion import Converter # added this lien causes error to be raised
from itertools import combinations
```

In `Sources/preprocessing/conversion.py` I don't have anything imported.

Below are the sequence of files that are run because error arise:

```
sources\__init__.py
sources\preparation\__init__.py
sources\prepartion\features\__init__.py
sources\preparation\features\build_features.py
sources\preparation\features\get_qualified_edgdes.py
sources\preprocessing\__init__.py
sources\preprocessing\apply_preprocessing.py
\\error raise
```

The error is raised when I import a class from `Sources.Preprocessing.convertion` as shown below. In `source/preparation/features/get_qualified_edges.py`:

```
from Sources.Preprocessing.convertion import Converter # added this lien causes error to be raised
```

Let me know if you folks need more information about this problem.

What I want to know is: **Why does this problem occur?**
I solved the problem when I moved `Converter` from `Sources.Preprocessing.convertion` to `Sources.Preparation.Data.conversion`.

#### Observation

What I observed is that the error disappeared when there are no "cross" imports between `Sources.Preprocessing.modules_A` (imported in `Sources.Preparation.modules_C`) and `Sources.Preparation.modules_B` (imported in `Sources.Preprocessing.modules_D`).

That's it. There are no direct "cross" imports between modules and instead there are "cross" imports between parent modules, if that makes any sense.

Comment: Your import structure is complicated so it's hard to be sure but I suspect you  have module A that imports B, and B (directly or indirectly) imports A. And A defines a function that B needs *after* its `import B` statement. Imports in Python are executable statements, so the interpreter pauses processing A when told to import B. That may mean that a needed `def` in A hasn't yet been processed when B is imported.

Answer (score 1):

The problem lies in you are introducing cyclic imports from your files.

For files witin `sources/preprocessing`, you are importing things from `source/preparation`. But those files, in-turn, import things from `source/preprocessing`.

Once you have import chains that goes something like

> A.py -> **B.py -> C.py -> B.py** -> E.py

(direct cycle)

or

> A.py -> **B.py -> C.py -> D.py-> B.py** -> E.py

(indirect cycle)

then it won't be able to continue importing the modules since it is impossible for it to terminate.

A simple way to over come this in python is using local import.

For example, instead of

```py
from Sources.Preprocessing.convertion import Converter 
# more code.....

class A:

  def foo():
    bar = Converter()
```

you can instead use local imports like

```py
# more code.....

class A:

  def foo():
    from Sources.Preprocessing.convertion import Converter 

    bar = Converter()
```

such that it only imports before you are actually using the object. This will avoids importing everything at the start, which avoid cyclic imports.

---

**Edit:**

In short, to answer OP's question of this particular issue:

Somewhere in the code you initiated the import of **preprocessing** module.   (probably in  `sources\preparation\features\get_qualified_edgdes.py`? not too sure)
At this time, **preprocessing** is added to `sys.modules` namespace but as an empty module (place holder).

Later on in the same import chain, in the file `source/preparation/features/get_qualified_edges.py`, the line

```py
from Sources.Preprocessing.convertion import Converter
```

tries to import `convertion` from **Preprocessing** module, but it will find an empty module (since it's still in the process of importing it) and hence failed to find the corresponding name (`convertion` in this case).

Comment: I understand your point, but how does this applies to my case? take a look at line that cause error when added in this way```from Sources.Preprocessing.convertion import Converter``` convertion.py does not import anything. So in my case, there is no any of direct or indirect cycle as you state. import just ended at convertion.py. I believe my question demands slightly different solution.

Comment: I would think that `from Sources.Preparation.Features.get_qualified_edges import ...` from `preprocessing/apply_preprocessing.py` is the main cause of your import problem.

Looking at the snipets, **preparation/features/__Init__.py** 's `from .get_qualified_edges import *`  eventually creates an import chains leads to **preprocessing/apply_preprocessing** 's `from Sources.Preparation.Features.get_qualified_edges import ...`

Comment: You should either refactor `preparation\features\get_qualified_edgdes.py` or use the proposed method of local imports. As for the reason of it only throwing errors with the additional `from Sources.Preprocessing.convertion import Converter`, it's because modern python will allow cyclic imports, where when it happens it will make it points to an empty module. But during the import of that module, if you refers to functions or class within it, it sees that it's an empty module (as it hasn't finish importing yet) and throw the exception of `ImportError` of not finding the referred name.

Comment: Can you show what import chain that I create looks like? I just don't see why there are circular import in my cases since all of the imported file (other than __init__.py) import other file directly. I can see the same file get imported twice, but no circular import. Please show me what it looks like.

Comment: You'd have to include more of your files content as your current description is insufficient where some files within the chain are missing.