# Scons fails to import _args_from_interpreter_flags

Tags: python, import, scons

Im trying to compile [Godot engine](https://github.com/okamstudio/godot) following the instructions [here](http://www.godotengine.org/wiki/doku.php?id=compiling_linux)

When I run `scons bin/godot` as the tutorial says, I get the following error:

```
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags:
  File "/home/grayfox/github/godot2/godot/SConstruct", line 9:
    import multiprocessing
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/__init__.py", line 65:
    from multiprocessing.util import SUBDEBUG, SUBWARNING
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/util.py", line 40:
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
```

The SConstruct file starts this way:

```
EnsureSConsVersion(0,14);

import string
import os
import os.path
import glob
import sys
import methods
import multiprocessing
...
```

If I try to run `python SConstruct` I get an error complaining about missing functions defined by scons (i.e. the script fails **after** doing all the imports).

Commenting `import multiprocessing` fixes the issue but I don't want to modify that file, as I would have to revert the change if I ever make a pull request. The project is quite active so I believe this has something to do with my local configuration.

Any ideas why the script is failing to import `_args_from_interpreter_flags` only if I execute it via scons?

**[UPDATE]**

I did a fresh Gentoo install and the problem persists. I did some tests and I found this:

In a python terminal>

```
>>> import SCons.Script
>>> from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.__file__
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/SCons/compat/_scons_subprocess.pyc'
```

But the output is different if I do this:

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.__file__
'/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.pyc'
```

So I update my question: Is this a bug? Can anybody reproduce it in other distros? If it's a bug, should I report it to Gentoo or to SCons?

**[ANOTHER UPDATE]**

Adding `temp.extend([os.path.join(x, 'lib64') for x in prefs])` did't work, same error.

Adding `print sys.path` at the beginning of the compact module gives:

```
['/usr/lib64/python-exec/python2.7/scons-local-2.3.0',
 '/usr/lib64/python-exec/python2.7/scons-local',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/lib32/scons-2.3.0',
 '/usr/lib32/scons-2.3.0',
 '/usr/local/lib32/scons-2.3.0',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons-2.3.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons-2.3.0',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons-2.3.0',
 '/usr/lib64/scons-2.3.0',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/lib32/scons',
 '/usr/lib32/scons',
 '/usr/local/lib32/scons',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/scons',
 '/usr/lib64/scons',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/RBTools-0.6-py2.7.egg',
 '/usr/lib64/python27.zip',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7',      #It's here, so what's the problem?
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/plat-linux2',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode']
```

Comment: I can see from the error message that it appears that you are using Python 2.7, but what do you get on the command line if you type: "python --version"? SCons does not work with python 3+, and Im suspecting that may be the problem.

Comment: `python --version` outputs `Python 2.7.5`. I also tried switching to python 3 (using gentoo's `select python`), but I get the same error. It seems scons uses a wrapper file which selects the correct interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in Gentoo's scons-2.3.0 and scons-2.3.1 ebuilds (see [bug report](https://bugs.gentoo.org/507850)). It has been fixed in versions 2.3.1-r1 and higher.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as if this isn't really a problem connected to SCons directly. You might have an alien "subprocess" module/package installed in your system. Also check out [Cannot import name _args_from_interpreter_flags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235919/cannot-import-name-args-from-interpreter-flags) which seems to be related.

Based on your updated question: I tried to compile Godot on my machine (Python 2.7.3, SCons 2.3.1, Ubuntu 12.04 LTS) and it's running fine, so the problem is not related to the provided SConstruct (and its supporting build description files in subfolders). The "`_scons_subprocess`" module gets used only when the import of the original "`subprocess.py`" fails. So I suspect that the SCons start script sets up a wrong `sys.path`, which may happen under 64bit (see issue http://scons.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=2657 ).

After you added "`temp.extend([os.path.join(x, 'lib64') for x in prefs])`", your "`print sys.path`" statement shows paths like "/usr/lib64/python-exec" in its output. A Google search turned up the page http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-985402-start-0.html for me. It describes an issue with Gentoo, where programs are installed as links to `pip`. Please follow the given advice and see if this fixes your problem.

Comment: Check my question update. Effectively I have another subprocess module, but it's scons's.