# Trouble importing name '_args_from_interpreter_flags' from 'subprocess'

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am attempting to write a Python script to download and unzip hundreds of files from an AWS server. As I understand it, these tasks are I/O-bound tasks, so I would like to multi-thread this task to speed up processing times.

Since I am new to Python, I've been reading guides like [this one](https://shuzhanfan.github.io/2017/12/parallel-processing-python-subprocess/) and [that one](https://www.infoworld.com/article/3315121/python-threading-and-subprocesses-explained.html) on multithreading and multiprocessing.

Both of the above links suggest code to import methods from the `subprocess` library, but I am running into trouble completing these imports. The second link above suggests the following code to illustrate multithreading:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool as ProcessPool

from urllib.request import urlopen

def run_tasks(function, args, pool, chunk_size=None):
    results = pool.map(function, args, chunk_size)
    return results

def work(n):    
    with urlopen("https://www.google.com/#{n}") as f:
        contents = f.read(32)
    return contents

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [x for x in range(1,100)]
    
    # Run the task using a thread pool
    
    t_p = ThreadPool()
    result = run_tasks(work, numbers, t_p)    
    print (result)

    t_p.close()
```

When I tried running this script, I got the following error with traceback:

```
PS C:\Users\USERNAME> & "C:/Users/USERNAME/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe" "h:/Post-Processing/API Query/Python Test/subprocess_test/subprocess.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:/Post-Processing/API Query/Python Test/subprocess_test/subprocess.py", line 38, in <module>
    t_p = ThreadPool()
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\dummy\__init__.py", line 123, in Pool
    from ..pool import ThreadPool
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 26, in <module>
    from . import util
  File "C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\util.py", line 17, in <module>
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
ImportError: cannot import name '_args_from_interpreter_flags' from 'subprocess' (h:\PSO Post-Processing\API Query\Python Test\subprocess_test\subprocess.py)
```

I found [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235919/cannot-import-name-args-from-interpreter-flags), in which the answer suggests adding

```
from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
```

to the list of imports. However, when I added this line, the import error seems to shift into my current script:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "h:/Post-Processing/API Query/Python Test/subprocess_test/subprocess.py", line 20, in <module>
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
  File "h:\Post-Processing\API Query\Python Test\subprocess_test\subprocess.py", line 20, in <module>
    from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
ImportError: cannot import name '_args_from_interpreter_flags' from 'subprocess' (h:\PSO Post-Processing\API Query\Python Test\subprocess_test\subprocess.py)
```

I am now suspecting that something is wrong with my Python installation, but I am not sure how to troubleshoot it.

I am running Windows 10 on a work computer and using Visual Studio Code as my editor. According to Visual Studio Code, I'm running `Python 3.7.6 64-bit ('Continuum': virtualenv)`. I found that I have `subprocess.py` installed at

```
"C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\Lib\subprocess.py"
```

and this `subprocess.py` file indeed has a segment with

```
def _args_from_interpreter_flags():
    """Return a list of command-line arguments reproducing the current
    settings in sys.flags, sys.warnoptions and sys._xoptions."""
    flag_opt_map = {
        'debug': 'd',
        # 'inspect': 'i',
        # 'interactive': 'i',
        'dont_write_bytecode': 'B',
        'no_site': 'S',
        'verbose': 'v',
        'bytes_warning': 'b',
        'quiet': 'q',
        # -O is handled in _optim_args_from_interpreter_flags()
    }
    args = _optim_args_from_interpreter_flags()
    for flag, opt in flag_opt_map.items():
        v = getattr(sys.flags, flag)
        if v > 0:
            args.append('-' + opt * v)

    if sys.flags.isolated:
        args.append('-I')
    else:
        if sys.flags.ignore_environment:
            args.append('-E')
        if sys.flags.no_user_site:
            args.append('-s')

    # -W options
    warnopts = sys.warnoptions[:]
    bytes_warning = sys.flags.bytes_warning
    xoptions = getattr(sys, '_xoptions', {})
    dev_mode = ('dev' in xoptions)

    if bytes_warning > 1:
        warnopts.remove("error::BytesWarning")
    elif bytes_warning:
        warnopts.remove("default::BytesWarning")
    if dev_mode:
        warnopts.remove('default')
    for opt in warnopts:
        args.append('-W' + opt)

    # -X options
    if dev_mode:
        args.extend(('-X', 'dev'))
    for opt in ('faulthandler', 'tracemalloc', 'importtime',
                'showalloccount', 'showrefcount', 'utf8'):
        if opt in xoptions:
            value = xoptions[opt]
            if value is True:
                arg = opt
            else:
                arg = '%s=%s' % (opt, value)
            args.extend(('-X', arg))

    return args
```

Given all this information, I am sure that I'm missing a simple detail that's stopping the threading code from working. I appreciate any help you can give.

Thank you!!

Comment: It looks like you have a file named `subprocess.py` in the current directory, and that one is being imported instead of the "real" one.

Comment: Oh thank you! I named the script I was running subprocess.py without realizing it was causing my very errors! Now the script works. Thank you, John Gordon!

For my knowledge, if I ```import``` something, does Python first look in the script's directory, and then in the libraries folder if the first search fails?

Comment: Yes, the script's own directory is always first in the search path.